# add php variable in url link

Tags: php, html

I am printing out some variables within a table using a for each loop, I would like to pass one of these variables `"car"` to a URL. The URL should look as follows;

```
http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=[VALUE_OF_CARS_HERE]&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl
```

My for each successfully prints the results and looks as follows;

```
foreach ($this->books as $book) {
echo '<td>'.$book->id.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$book->title.'</td>';
}
```

I have tried the following;

```
echo '<td>http://www.google.co.uk/search?q='.$book->title.'&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl</td>';
```

This simply prints out the text but it's not 'clickable';

```
http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Cars&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: maybe put it inside a href? `<a href="http://www.google...">Text</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem doesn't come from the php side of your code but come from a simple forgotten tag. To make a link clickable, you need to use the  tag like :

```
<a href="your link">your text</a>
```

Try :

```
echo '<td><a href="http://www.google.co.uk/search?q='.$book->title.'&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl">link text</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put an `a` (anchor) tag to make it clickable.

```
$url = 'http://www.google.co.uk/search?q='.$book->title.'&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl';
echo '<td><a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

As per others answers you need to put it inside an anchor tag such as:

```
$link = 'http://www.google.co.uk/search?q='.$book->title.'&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl';
echo '<td><a href="' . $link .'">' . $book->title . '</a></td>';
```

However, I would also recommend using [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on your book title within the URL, so..

```
$link = 'http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=' . urlencode($book->title) . '&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl';
echo '<td><a href="' . $link .'">' . $book->title . '</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the url need the a tag.

Based on

```
echo '<td>http://www.google.co.uk/search?q='.$book->title.'&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl</td>';
```

you can do this:

```
echo '<td><a href="http://www.google.co.uk/search?q='.$book->title.'&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl">http://www.google.co.uk/search?q='.$book->title.'&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl</td></a>';
```

or this:

```
echo '<td><a href="http://www.google.co.uk/search?q='.$book->title.'&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl">My Link Title</td></a>';
```